# Redirection of URL with question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

Hi I need help with a RewriteRule to forward the folling url:

```
https://example.com/ipsum-lorem-amit/?lang=en
```

to

```
https://example.com/en/a-newpage-here
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tipsum-lorem-amit/?lang=en [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/en/a-newpage-here [R,L]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: @anubhava I updated my post, thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule as your `**top most rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^tipsum-lorem-amit/?$ /%1/a-newpage-here? [R=301,NC,L]
```